# TSQL Select column values which has multiple values in another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Maybe someone can help me out of this tsql script problem: i have a Table Company  like:

| class | name | party |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company1 | 6 |
| 3 | B-company | 14 |
| 3 | C-company | 12 |
| 3 | C-company | 12 |
| 4 | Company33 | 50 |
| 4 | Company33 | 50 |

i need to show all column data (select * from Company) for "class" numbers which has multiple values in column "Party". For this example: class column number 3 has multiple values in column party. 3 - 14 and 3 - 12

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANY
WHERE CLASS IN
(SELECT CLASS FROM COMPANY 
GROUP BY CLASS
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PARTY) > 1)
```

If I've understood your question correctly, this should be what you are after.
In the WHERE clause, we use a subquery to find the class number that have more than one party that are different to one another. We group by the CLASS in the subquery, and ensure that the group has at least 2 different values for the party column. From the sample you have provided this should only return class 3 within the subquery.

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly and this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure,but could you please try the following

```
   WITH COMPANY(CLASS,NAME,PARTY) AS
    (
        SELECT 1,   'Company1',     6

           UNION ALL
        SELECT 3,   'B-company',    14
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ,  'C-company',    12
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ,  'C-company',    12
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 ,  'Company33',    50
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 ,  'Company33' ,   50
 )
 SELECT C.CLASS,C.NAME,C.PARTY
 FROM COMPANY AS C
 WHERE EXISTS
  (
     SELECT 1 FROM COMPANY AS C2 WHERE C.CLASS=C2.CLASS AND C.PARTY<>C2.PARTY 
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

With table company records where you want to see all columns for the scenario where the class column has multiple values for the party, here is a solution:

```
        WITH many_parties AS (
    SELECT
        class
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                class
            FROM
                company
            GROUP BY
                class,
                party
        ) smmry
    GROUP BY
        class
    HAVING
        COUNT(1) > 1
)
SELECT
    cmpy.*
FROM
         company cmpy
    JOIN many_parties mp ON mp.class = cmpy.class
```